# Substituting characters from alphabet array with input string

Tags: java

I am creating a method that when given a substitution code it returns the substitution code which can be used to decode any message

An example of what I mean is found below

```
English Alphabet = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
substitution     = XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN
Output I want    = OYWVGXNDMEJSHZQPFTCKLBUARI
```

As you can see above '**A**' in the *Substitution* maps to '**O**' on the *English Alphabet* hence why in the *output* '**O**' is the first letter. '**B**' in the *Substitution* maps to '**Y**'in the *English Alphabet* hence why it is the second letter and so fourth...

The code I created

```
public static String getRev(String s)
{
    
    char normalChar[]
            = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    
    String revString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {

            if (s.indexOf(i) == normalChar[j])
            {
                revString += normalChar[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return revString;
}
```

l

```
input =           "XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN"
Expected output = "OYWVGXNDMEJSHZQPFTCKLBUARI"
My output =       "XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN"
```

Comment: Can you explain the code you tried and what your thought behind it is/was? What caught my eyes first is that you only have one single array normalChar with the alphabet but nowhere can i see any data structure that you even use to map your normal alphabet to your substitution alphabet. The substitution alphabet seems to be not declared anywhere in your code so I'm really not sure what your original idea with your code was and how you expected it to do the mapping from normal alphabet to your substitution.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS The idea behind the code I tried to make was to use an array with characters of the alphabet and compared it against an input alphabet like shown above to get the output. The reason I did it this way is because I created a mono alphabetic cipher which and I thought I could use that code to try and solve this problem but clearly not.

Comment: @Lino I tried this at first but it doesn't return anything when I do it that way, that's why I tried indexOf but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @tenderguitar Ahh, so the String you pass into that method is the substitution alphabet? This would probably be a lot clearer if you called that variable something like `subsitutionAlphabet` instead of just `s` (Just a hint that variable naming is important ;)

Comment: 1) `s.indexOf(i)` means that a codePoint `i` is sought in the input string s, it should be `s.charAt(i)` 2) `normalChar` array contains lower case letters while input `s` is supposed to contain only uppercase - these are the two reasons of condition `s.indexOf(i) == normalChar[j]` being always `false`, thus resulting in an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

1. For input `"XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN"` and the same substitution `"XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN"` a "normal" alphabet should be returned.
2. To get `"OYWVGXNDMEJSHZQPFTCKLBUARI"` for the provided substitution and normal alphabet as input, an index of char from the `input` is located in the `substitution` and this index is used to find a char in normal alphabet:

```java
public static String getRev(String s) {
    String normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String substitution = "XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN";
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        int index = substitution.indexOf(c);
        if (index >-1) {
            sb.append(normal.charAt(index));
        }
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(getRev("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")); // OYWVGXNDMEJSHZQPFTCKLBUARI
System.out.println(getRev("XVSHJQEMZKTUIGAPOYLRWDCFBN")); // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: If the intended use is only for the 26 letters of the english alphabet, one could replace `normal.charAt(index)` with `(char) (index + 'A')`